# How to generate notification when the application is closed for event reminder?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-service

I am a beginner in mobile development, I am working on a Birthday application that will generate notification few days before and on the birthday of a person. I am not understanding what kind of service is to be used to keep track of the days till the birthday when the application is not running, so far I have managed to generate notification on click with the following code.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, ItemClickListener {

    public void sendOnBirthdayChannelRemainingDays(View v){
        String message = "This is a very happy birthday to you message";
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        activityIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", message);
        activityIntent.addCategory(Intent. CATEGORY_LAUNCHER ) ;
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext()
        , 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_BIRTHDAY_DAYSREMAINING_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gift_box)
                .setContentTitle("Birthday")
                .setContentText("Its one day before your birthday")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it and found the solution. We will have to use AlarmManager class with system service using pending intents to pass the specified date. The OS alarm service will notify us on the specified date and wake up the device.

Just have to call this function in MainActivity

```
private void setAlarm(String date) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("date", date); 
    

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    String dateandtime = date + " " + "10:00";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy hh:mm");
    try {
        Date date1 = formatter.parse(dateandtime);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm set to" + date1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date1.getTime(), pendingIntent);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> And create a NotificationReceiver class

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String date = bundle.getString("dateString");

    //On notification click

    Intent clickNotficationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    clickNotficationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    clickNotficationIntent.putExtra("dateString", date);
    clickNotficationIntent.putExtra("shan", "myMessage");
    
    //Click Pending Intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntentClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  2000, clickNotficationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //Notification Builder
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_BIRTHDAY_DAYSREMAINING_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gift_box)
            .setContentTitle("Birthday")
            .setContentText("Its one day before your birthday")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntentClick)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

}

CHANNEL_BIRTHDAY_DAYSREMAINING_ID is my notification channel, we just need to create a new class and define the channel there.